# SQL - Multiply two Columns from two tabels

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to multiply the value of a product from table A with the amount of purchases from table b and write the SUM in a column in table B.

```
table a
--------
product
value
```

```
table b
--------
memberID
freuency of purchase of product
Sum of purchases
```

Comment: which relation exist between the tables ??

Comment: Table A list all products and its price. Table B list the amount of purchases of product. That product is the only relation. Table B -> Table A (one to many)

Comment: @Christian - there is no one to many relation in what you laid out here...table b would need to have productID in it for that relation to exist.  Table B really makes no sense as you define it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work that's if you have relationship between two tables, like productID in both tables , Or similar to this, try it out

```
Select tA.ProductsValue * tB.TotalPurchases as TotalMoney , ProductID

From TableA  ta
Join ( select Count(purchases) as TotalPurchases, productID   
       from tableB
       Group by ProductID 
      ) tB on tA.ProductID = tB.ProductID
```

Comment: thanks for help. Unfortunatly there is no productID. There just is a table with values for each product in Table A and the frequency of purchases of these products in Table B.